# Scheduled Powershell script (WindowStyle Hidden) terminating automatically

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduling

I need to schedule powershell script which calls bat script internally and runs every minute.

**script1.bat**
*some echo commands which writes to csv file.*

**script2.ps1:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod <URL>
./script1.bat
```

**script3.ps1**

```
./script2.ps1
sleep 60
```

So script3.ps1 scheduled with the below command in cmd.

```
start /min powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command .\script2.ps1
```

So the scheduled script(script3.ps1) was running every minute as expected. But after some couple of hours the scripts terminated automatically by it's own. To check whether the hidden process is running or not with the below command.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "CommandLine LIKE '%powershell  -WindowStyle Hidden%'"
```

I didn't see the process running after couple of hours. Can anyone suggest why the background hidden running process  gets killed.

Comment: What's in `new_reset_stats_scheduler.ps1`?

Comment: Sorry it was typo..It will call script2.ps1 everytime and sleep for 60 secs.
start /min powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command .\script2.ps1

Comment: Check the task scheduler logs to see if any of the processes in this chain exit with an exit code other than 0

Comment: I didn't scheduled either by schtasks or task scheduler (gui) still I need to check the logs? If so please help me to check.

Comment: You didn't schedule it, but you expect it to automatically restart itself every minute? I must be missing something here...

Comment: Let's be more clear here I scheduled the script by below command.
start /min powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command .\script2.ps1                                                      does it scheduled via schtasks or task scheduler? Not sure here if so please let me know how to check further thanks

Comment: `start /min` _doesn't schedule anything_ - it just starts a new process in a separate window

Comment: Okay,got it. Please help me with some commands to schedule the script3.ps1.Thanks again!